# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE all fields wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pdo

I want update all fields values  if it exists or insert a new values in a table if the values did not already exist.

I write following code, But I don't know why doesn't  work.

```
  $query = $wpdb->prepare (
    "INSERT INTO ".$wpdb->prefix."fafa
        (id, title, liveprice, changing, lowest,topest,time)
    VALUES
        (%d, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        title = %s,
        liveprice = %s,
        changing = %s ,
        lowest = %s,
        topest = %s,
        time = %s",
    1,
    trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue),
    trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue),
    trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue),
    trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue),
    trim($row->item(8)->nodeValue),
    trim($row->item(10)->nodeValue)
);
```

Comment: let me know once this is working

Answer (score -2):

Please use wordpress default query for `update` record and `insert` record

see this link for update and insert query if records exists or not

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/php-tracking-visitors-check-if-row-exists

Comment: I can't update with this way.. IF you Can... Please Fix Top code... Thanks ..@kuldip Makadiya